# Rotate a 2D plot with respect to another 2D plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

By using this data:

```
x <- (-9.56257588328661,-9.32048556072206,-9.07839522647581,-8.8363048806259,-8.59421452325033,-8.35212415442714,-8.11003377423433,-7.86794338274994,-7.62585298005199,-7.38376256621848,-7.14167214132746,
-6.89958170545693,-6.65749125868491,-6.41540080108944,-6.17331033274852,-5.93121985374018,-5.68912936414245,-5.44703886403333,-5.20494835349086,-4.96285783259305,-4.72076730141793,-4.47867676004351,
-4.23658620854782,-3.99449564700888,-3.7524050755047,-3.51031449411332,-3.26822390291274,-3.026133301981,-2.7840426913961,-2.54195207123608,-2.29986144157896,-2.05777080250275,-1.81568015408548,
-1.57358949640516,-1.33149882953982,-1.08940815356747,0.847317468566159,0.605226774613874,0.363136071788658,0.121045360168516,0.121045360168516,0.363136089144421,0.605226826681189,0.847317572700783,
1.08940832712519,1.3314990898764,1.57358986087637,1.81568064004709,2.05777142731055,2.2998622225887,2.54195302580355,2.78404383687707,3.02613465573123,3.26822548228801,3.5103163164694,3.75240715819737,
3.9944980073939,4.23658886398097,4.47867972788057,4.72077059901465,4.96286147730522,5.20495236267425,5.44704325504371,5.68913415433558,5.93122506047186,6.1733159733745,6.4154068929655,6.65749781916683,
6.89958875190046,7.14167969108839,7.38377063665259,7.62586158851503,7.8679525465977,8.11004351082257,8.35213448111163,8.59422545738686,8.83631643957023,9.07840742758371,9.32049842134931,9.56258942078898)

y <- (19.0666307196427,18.0071347931614,16.9804259667753,15.9862852584879,15.0244936863046,14.0948322682304,13.1970820222693,12.3310239664272,11.4964391187079,10.6931084971172,9.92081311965921,9.17933400433844,
8.46845216916017,7.7879486321292,7.13760441125009,6.51720052452788,5.92651798996712,5.36533782557308,4.83344104934986,4.33060867930271,3.85662173343621,3.41126122975516,2.99430818626433,2.605543620969,
2.24474855187304,1.91170399698262,1.60619097430072,1.32799050183303,1.07688359758527,0.85265127956086,0.655074565765517,0.483934474203352,0.33901202287916,0.220088229798193,0.12694411296502,0.0593606903842101,
0.0171189800610136,0,0.00778476820619289,0.0402543026837066,0.0971896214380195,0.178371742473928,0.283581683795319,0.412600463408353,0.565209099316689,0.741188609525352,0.94032001203982,1.16238432486421,
1.40716256600308,1.67443575346238,1.9639849052453,2.27559103935823,2.60903517380461,2.96409832658992,3.34056151571917,3.73820575919694,4.1568120750278,4.59616148121631,5.05603499576796,5.53621363668708,
6.03647842197847,6.55661036964739,7.09639049769794,7.65559982413561,8.23401936696428,8.83143014418988,9.44761317381585,10.0823494738486,10.7354200622915,11.4066059571505,12.0956881764293,12.8024477381327,
13.5266656602669,14.2681229608356,15.0266006578429,15.8018797692955,16.5937413131967,17.4019663075519,18.2263357703655,19.0666307196427)

df <- data.frame(x = x,y = y)
```

I am plotting a 2D plot which looks like this:
[image]

I have several plots like this. Now I want to combine those several 2D plots to form a 3D plot. Such that, 2nd 2D plot is rotated with respect to 1st 2D plot by some angle say 45 degrees. And similarly, all those  2D plots are needed to fit into a 3D plot with a certain angle in between each of them.

The final 3D plot looks like this:
[image]

FYI: Each 2D plot is stored in a separate data frame as mentioned above. I need to access and transform each data frame with respect to others.